# Show Dialog over an Activity/screen that is not owned by you

Tags: android

I have a requirement where Activity A starts another screen (Screen B) based on configuration provided to it. This new screen could be 
- Another Activity
- A react native screen
- Webview hosting some link.

And after opening Screen B, Activity A needs to show a dismissible dialog , which shows Screen B in the background (**Dialog appears on Screen B, but is owned by Activity A**)

How could I achieve this?

**Note: We do not have option of controlling screen B we only know which screen to open.**

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: You can create a `static boolean` in `Class B` and control it from `class A` or where do you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot normally show a dialog over another activity as it's outside your task stack, but you could try setting your dialog window layout type to [TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) (using the [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission).

Google "android draw over other apps" for implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with the webview  content ie, you can't add alert dialogue on the outside task

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
I am not sure but may be its help you.You make a BaseActivity() and in the BaseActivity() you register broadcast receiver() in the onRecive() of broadcast you can init the dialog box.

Step 2:
Your activity B will extend the BaseActivity().

Step 3:
At the time of calling actvity B you broadcast the reciver.

I hope its help you.